# Resteasy proxy jackson mapping/deserialization

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, resteasy

I try to switch my Resteasy REST clients (3.0.8) to using the proxy mechanism as this looks really nice to me. I can successfully fire the REST requests, but now I need to map/deserialize the response. Here comes the code:

RestRequest.java:

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://127.0.0.1:8080/backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/");
CategoryClient categoryClient = target.proxy(CategoryClient.class);
categoryList = categoryClient.getCategories();
```

CategoryClient.java (proxy interface):

```
public interface CategoryClient {
    @GET
    @Path("categories")
    @JsonProperty("categories")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Category> getCategories();
```

Category.java (target model):

```
public class Category {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Asset> assetList;
    // getter & setters
}
```

JSON reply I get and need to map:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/categories{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/categories/search"
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "categories" : [ {
      "name" : "monkeys",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/categories/0"
        },
        "assetList" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/categories/0/assetList"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "donkeys",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/categories/1"
        },
        "assetList" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/categories/1/assetList"
        }
      }
    }
    ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 5,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Now I need a mechanism to map the response to `List<Category>`, currently it is only giving a

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of 
java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
```

What steps do I need to make the mapping work?

Comment: assetList does not look like an array in your json.

Comment: This is the output of spring-data-rest. If I request the assetList resource I do get an array with similar JSON layout.

Comment: Then why are you trying to parse a different format from what it given from an output? I don't get it.

Comment: The format is JSON in both cases. By spring-data-rest on the server side it is obviously only embedded. The client application is not a spring application. It relies on Resteasy and fasterxml.jackson. If I get this work together it will save huge loads of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson annotations are effective only when applied to a class which you deserialize. The simplest way to achieve your goal is to create a class hierarchy which represents response structure:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Response {
    private Embedded embedded;
    // getters and setters here
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Embedded {
    private List<Category> categories;
    // getters and setters here
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Category {
    private String name;
    // getters and setters here
}
```

Then you will be able to get categories names. I was also looking for a conversion options, but it does not seem possible.
The best thing I found possible is to restructure your response using @JsonDeserialize annotation:

```
@JsonDeserialize(converter = ResponseConverter.class)
class Response {
    private List<String> categories;
    // getters and setters
}

class ResponseConverter implements Converter<Map<String, ?>, Response> {
    Response convert(Map<String, ?> jsonInput) {
        // convert jsonInput to response and return
    }
    // implement getInputType and getOutputType methods here
}
```